# Do replication and partitioning come out of the box when using serivces (DynamoDB , Azure Database for MySql) from cloud providers (AWS, Azure etc.)?

Tags: architecture, cloud, system-design

I am preparing for a system design interview and observed that any tutorial and guide addresses these 3 very important concepts: availability, replication and consistency.

What it's not clear for me is when should we use them. So far I understood that they have to be ensured by the development team only when using IaaS (Infrastructure as a service) because we purchase resources not services, so we have to set-up our db, application, queues etc. instances. Is this correct?

On the other hand, we can bypass setting up the DB by ourselves and purhcase Storage as a Service from a cloud services provider (e.g. Azure Databse for MySql). In my head I think that in this case Microsoft is responsible to guarantee availability and replication (e.g. at any time there is at least one instance running which contains all the required data).

Again, I'm not experienced in system design and architecture, so please correct me if I said only stupid nonsense.